# How to connect UILabel, UIPickerView, to UIButton returning results?

Tags: ios, json, uibutton, uilabel, uipickerview

I'm trying to connect a button to a `UILabel` that returns text from a `UIPickerView`, so that when the button is pressed, it returns JSON results that correspond to the text in the selected row. But I'm not seeking assistance fetching or assigning the strings from the array to the json, I simply need help connecting the button the JSON according the text selected in the button (also shown in the `UILabel`).

This is my current code (implementation file):

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad];
           self.catArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Children", @"Collaboration", @"Dating", @"Design", @"Education", @"Event",nil];
                     self.pickerView = catArray;
     }

   -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
            return 1;
     }


   -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
            // This returns the number of rows in each component. We use the count of our array to determine the number of rows.
           return [self.catArray count];
    }

        #pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods

   -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row   forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
            return [self.catArray objectAtIndex:row];
     }


   - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row   inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
            self.label.text = [self.catArray objectAtIndex:row];
      }

   - (IBAction)pressedGo:(id)sender{


     }
```

Comment: you can simply use the text of UILabel if button & label text are same

Comment: @Bhupesh But there's only one button in the ViewController. How can the label text and the button be the same?

Comment: @iOSLove14 you mean you want to fetch data as per text show in label right?

Comment: @iOSLove14 can you show me the UI ?

Comment: @Chinttu-RoxeN-Ramani Yes, exactly!

Comment: `NSInteger selectedIndex = [picker selectedRowInComponent:0]; NSLog(@"%@",self.catArray[selectedIndex]);` try this code on `pressedGo:` method.

Comment: @iOSLove14 this code helps you?

Comment: @Chinttu-RoxeN-Ramani I'm trying it...now there's something going wrong with my JSON, so I can't tell...